# Digital Ocean, Django and Nginx not finding all static files

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, django-staticfiles, nginx-location

I have tried a lot of different things but all of the solutions I found are not helping.

I putting my corporate site on a digitalocean site on ubuntu 16.04 by following the digitalocean [directions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) (which have worked well before) but it is only serving some of the static files.

Here are the links to the images.

```html
<h3>Here is the image that doesn't load</h3>

<img src="http://206.189.161.104/static/images/frac_stack_1.jpg" alt="Image that doesn't load">

<h3>Here is the image that does load in the same folder</h3>

<img src="http://206.189.161.104/static/images/coil_pic.jpg" alt="Image that doesn't load" style="width:200px;height:200px;>
```

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 206.189.161.104;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static {
    root /home/dmckim/myproject;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/dmckim/myproject/myproject.sock;
}
}
```

I tried removing the trailing slash off the static (as shown above). I also tried changing root to alias and adding the static folder to the path but I had the same results.

Here is the code from my settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    '/home/dmckim/myproject/static/',
    '/home/dmckim/myproject/static/images/',
)
```

I also tried clearing collectstatic before collectingstatic again and I always run these commands after and make sure my browser cache is cleared.

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
sudo nginx -t && sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

My permission on the files are `-rw-rw-r--`, for the image that does load and the one that doesn't load. I also tried a lot of ways to change permissions (I don't really understand them but they were suggested in other posts). I even destoyed the server and started from scratch to make sure I didn't mess anything up with the permissions.

I don't see anything wrong with the nginx process logs or the access logs but the error logs show the following:

```
2018/05/31 13:04:19 [error] 11481#11481: *22 open() 
"/home/dmckim/myproject/static/images/frac_stack_1.jpg" failed (2: No such 
file or directory), client: 12.184.4.50, server: 206.189.161.104, request: 
"GET /static/images/frac_stack_1.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "206.189.161.104", 
referrer: "http://206.189.161.104/frac-stacks/"
```

The gunicorn logs show a 404 for the images that won't load.

Here is the www-data group `uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)`

Here is my group `uid=1000(dmckim) gid=1000(dmckim) groups=1000(dmckim),27(sudo)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file names are case sensitive. Your image is named "http://206.189.161.104/static/images/frac_stack_1.JPG" not "http://206.189.161.104/static/images/frac_stack_1.jpg".

```html
<h3>Here is the image that loads</h3>

<img src="http://206.189.161.104/static/images/frac_stack_1.JPG" alt="Image that doesn't load" style="width:200px;height:200px;">

<h3>Here is the other image that does load in the same folder</h3>

<img src="http://206.189.161.104/static/images/coil_pic.jpg" alt="Image that doesn't load" style="width:200px;height:200px;>
```

Note that your results may differ when running this locally. Windows isn't case sensitive, Linux is. See [this question for details](https://superuser.com/questions/881804/case-sensitive-file-extensions-in-windows-and-linux)

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I made that mistake. I must have looked at the file names 20 times and never noticed they were uppercase and since the django development server doesn't care about that I didn't think to look at that.

Comment: I've been there and done the same thing! Now, that mistake has bitten me enough that I know to check for it first!